# calculate the total value from the table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-8

**I want to display in table user id and total point he has for all him actions.**
i am trying to got these data by this query but doesn't work

```
$sum = ActionUser::with('user')->where('id','user_id')->where('id','action_id')->sum('point');
    dd($sum);
```

[image: this table]

Comment: Please show some effort and post the code you already have, this is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify $userId:

```
$sum = ActionUser::where('user_id', $userId)->sum('point');
```

Also you can use raw query, and it dont matter the versions of laravel or php:

```
SELECT SUM(point) FROM `action_users` WHERE `user_id` = $userId
```

Comment: i don't have $userId variable i want to show these data  in table in admin side